# Calculating expected profit in roulette problems

Tags: probability

I try to solve the following roulette problem using two approaches. And they seem to give different answers so I think I might have done something wrong but I have no idea what it is.

Consider a roulette with 37 possible outcomes, out of which 18 are red, 18 are black, and one is green. I have \$3 and I play for 3 rounds, betting \$1 on red in every round.

First approach: Calculate the expected balance after 3 rounds and get the expected profit.

$X_0=3\\
E[X_1]=4\cdot (18/37)+2\cdot (19/37)=(110/111)X_0\\
E[X_2]=(110/111)^2X_0\\
E[X_3]=(110/111)^3X_0=(110/111)^3\cdot 3$

$Profit = X = X_3-3\\
E[X]=E[X_3-3]=E[X_3]-E[3]=E[X_3]-3=(110/111)^3\cdot 3-3\approx-0.0803528$

Second approach: Calculate the expected profit of a round and use linearity of expectation to find the expected total profit.

$Profit = X=X_1+X_2+X_3\\
E[X]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]+E[X_3]=3\cdot ((-1)\cdot (19/37) + (1) \cdot (18/37))=-3/37\approx -0.081081$

I am quite sure the the second approach is correct but what's the problem with the first approach? Thanks in advance for guidance!

Comment: Why do you say $E(X_2)=(110/111)^2X_0$? If you wish to calculate $E(X_2)$ you need to recognize that the possible values of $X_2$ are $1,3,5$ and depend on the value of $X_1$. I suggest you look at the total law of expectation if you seek to use this approach: $$E(X_2)=E(X_2|X_1=2)P(X_1=2)+E(X_2|X_1=4)P(X_1=4)$$

Comment: Oh, I have inappropriately concluded that $E(X_2)=(110/111)E[X_1]$ based on the calculation of some slightly different problems without reasoning carefully. Thanks for pointing that out.